# can you check a hidden checkbox if it's immediate parent is hidden as well?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, checked

I would like to check and uncheck a hidden an HTML checkbox based on a related event.

Unfortunately when i attempt to do this and i look at dev tools in firefox and chrome. It does not seem to be possible.

I am using jQuery to check and uncheck the hidden checkbox. I can only do it if the checkbox is shown.

Thanks

Comment: Why not quickly make it visible (out of visibility) check it, hide it, then reattach it to its original place?

Comment: why do not you try to make normal hidden text? Like 1-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just work, but its attribute `checked` will not show in the devtool, you can use `console.log()` to test if checkbox is checked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #hiddenbox,
    #hiddenBox {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button1">click</button>
  <div id="hiddendiv">
    <input id="hiddenbox" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
      $('#hiddenbox').prop('checked', true);
      console.log($('#hiddenbox').prop('checked'));
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't realize the the devtools do not get updated. i just checked using console.log and i realized that the checkbox does change but that change is not reflected in the devtools.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `visibility:hidden` to hide your checkbox or use `opacity:0` ,you can also use `display:none`, then you can check if it's checked or not

in the snippet below , I checked the checkbox programaticly while the display is hidden using Jquery then test if the checkbox is checked or not

```js
$("button").on("click",()=>{
  $('input').prop('checked', true);
 if($('input').is(':checked')){
   console.log("checked")
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" style="display:none">
<button>Check the hidden checkbox</button>
```